# Scrape the last anchor href of each parent element (Using Ruby Nokogiri)

Tags: ruby, regex, web-scraping, nokogiri, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape the event info's href on JamBase using Nokogiri. Here is the url: http://www.jambase.com/shows/Shows.aspx?ArtistID=0&VenueID=0&City=Philadelphia&State=pa&Zip=19102&radius=0&StartDate=11/1/2013&EndDate=11/1/2014&Rec=False&pagenum=1&pasi=600

The event info's href is in the last anchor under td.toolCol. I can get all the the hrefs by using:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.jambase.com/shows/Shows.aspx?ArtistID=0&VenueID=0&City=Philadelphia&State=pa&Zip=19102&radius=0&StartDate=11/1/2013&EndDate=11/1/2014&Rec=False&pagenum=1&pasi=700"))

page.css("td.toolCol a").map{|x| x["href"]}.each{|f| puts f}
```

But I can't figure out how to just grab the last href. (FYI, sometimes the href is the 3rd element or the fourth. It would be best to just direct at the last.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the CSS `:last-*` pseudo classes, [`:last-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo) for example:

```
page.css('td.toolCol a:last-of-type').map { |x| x['href'] }
```